# How to add external JavaScript library via gradle in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, gradle

I got a project that does not contain Java code, it only contains html, css and JavaScript. Those files get zipped to a file that is deployed in a mashup platform as a widget.

Since I want to use external libraries like jQuery it would be pretty neat if I could get Gradle to set those libraries as external JavaScript libraries so IntelliJ IDEA would offer code completion for those libraries. By hand I can enable this via Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries -> . But I would love to have this done when I use `gradlew.bat idea` to create my IntelliJ project.

Currently my build.gradle looks like this:

```
group 'ProjectName'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    zip
}

dependencies {
    zip group: 'org.webjars', name: 'jquery', version: '2.2.0'
}

task zip(type: Zip) {
    destinationDir file('dest')
    archiveName 'Widget.wgt'
    from 'WidgetContent'
    include '**/*'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.10'
}
```

Is it possible to set IntelliJ IDEAs external libraries with gradle somehow in a project like this? And if so: how?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is possible if one were to figure out how IDEA configures external libraries in it's project files and write the equivalent `idea{}` gradle config.